# How do I show JSON HTTP 422 responses to the user when using jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Hello i am having this weird issue with my json, i am trying to return error messages and display on my page, i have tried soo many solutions i have found online but i keep getting either 'undefined' or 'null' or nothing at all depending on what i try, this is my javascript:

```
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/auth/register",
                headers : {
                    'X-XSRF-Token': $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr("content")
                },
                data: {
                    email: $scope.d.email,
                    password: $scope.d.password,
                    password_confirmation: $scope.d.password_confirmation
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    //
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $scope.d.errors = data.responseJSON;
                    alert($scope.d.errors);

                }
            });
```

this is what is returned:

```
{"name":["The name field is required."]}
```

Comment: My mistake. I misunderstood your question. I edited your question title to include a clearer problem statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are returning a `422`, then jQuery will invoke your fail/error callback. The signature for an error/fail callback is:

`Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`

In the case of the error jQuery does not parse the response for you, you need to manually do it yourself if you want access to it, making your error callback look like:

```
function(xhr, status, err) {
    var responseJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    $scope.d.errors = responseJSON;
    alert($scope.d.errors);
    // do stuff with your error messages presumably...
}
```